# how to check in c# whether request is sent from fancybox or normal web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i have two form in my sites but both are submitting on same action ,
 i form open in fancy-box and one open in a normal page ,
you can i know that the request is made from fancy-box
 or the noraml page , because if form submission fails due
 to validation i have to send back the same view with validation
 errors from which user made request .

```
public ActionResult SubtmitForm(contact model)
{
 // here i will check whether request is from fancy-box form or from normal web page form 
}
```

***Note* : i am using asp.net mvc3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built in to say where a request originated, in particular not from how the browser requested it.

You need to build this into your model and populate the data in javascript (or otherwise).

Something like a `public bool FromFancyBox { get; set;};` on the model with a `HiddenFor` on the view.

When opening the fancybox you set the value to `true` and when closing it, you set it to false (though there are other mechanisms).

In the controller, test for this property.